# bq multi-level nested repeated fields update

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am converting one of our bq tables schema to a multi-level nested schema

[image: this] to [image: this]

Schema:

[image]

Basically, I want the `orderId`, `orderItems` and `amount` copied to the array `orders` which is a struct with `orderId`, `orderItems` and `amount`. The problem is that the `orderItems` is itself a nested array.

The source and destination is the same record but copy from a one-level nested structure, to a multi-level nested structure.

(as of now, I am retaining the old schema and new schema in the same table and once the data is copied, will have to drop the old fields)

The query I am trying to use is

```sql
    update customers as a
    set orders = array(
        select as struct
            orderId, 
            array(
                select as struct 
                    oi.itemId, oi.quantity, oi.unitPrice from unnest(orderItems) as oi
                ) orderItems, 
            amount
        from customers
        where a.customerId = customerId
    ) where true
```

With this query, I am getting the error as `Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN.`

I tried a simple `SELECT` statement with the same concept and it also result in the same error.

```sql
select 
    customerId, 
    customerName, 
    array (select as struct 
        orderId, 
        array(select as struct oi.itemId, oi.quantity, oi.unitPrice), 
        amount
    from customers, unnest(orderItems) as oi
    where a.customerId = customerId
  ) from customers a
  where true
```

But if I do the same without the `unnest` it works.

```
select 
  customerId, 
  customerName
  array(
    select as struct 
      orderId, 
      orderItems,
      amount
      from customers
      where a.customerId = customerId
    )  
  from customers as a
```

Sample data:

[image]

Sample Output: (returned from a select stmt)

[image]

Sample schema (minified json)

```
[{"mode":"NULLABLE","name":"customerId","type":"STRING"},{"mode":"NULLABLE","name":"customerName","type":"STRING"},{"mode":"NULLABLE","name":"orderId","type":"STRING"},{"fields":[{"mode":"NULLABLE","name":"itemId","type":"STRING"},{"mode":"NULLABLE","name":"quantity","type":"FLOAT"},{"mode":"NULLABLE","name":"unitPrice","type":"FLOAT"}],"mode":"REPEATED","name":"orderItems","type":"RECORD"},{"mode":"NULLABLE","name":"amount","type":"FLOAT"},{"fields":[{"mode":"NULLABLE","name":"orderId","type":"STRING"},{"fields":[{"mode":"NULLABLE","name":"itemId","type":"STRING"},{"mode":"NULLABLE","name":"quantity","type":"FLOAT"},{"mode":"NULLABLE","name":"unitPrice","type":"FLOAT"}],"mode":"REPEATED","name":"orderItems","type":"RECORD"},{"mode":"NULLABLE","name":"amount","type":"FLOAT"}],"mode":"REPEATED","name":"orders","type":"RECORD"}]
```

Sample data (minified json):

```
[{"customerId":"ABC","customerName":"ABC Corp","orderId":"83282-0933","orderItems":[{"itemId":"AQ1929","quantity":"3.0","unitPrice":"21.2"},{"itemId":"AQ1922","quantity":"1.0","unitPrice":"1.5"},{"itemId":"AQ1901","quantity":"10.0","unitPrice":"0.5"}],"amount":"70.1","orders":[]},{"customerId":"XYZ","customerName":"XYZ and Co.","orderId":"89923-0393","orderItems":[{"itemId":"AQ1921","quantity":"1.0","unitPrice":"4.0"},{"itemId":"AQ1922","quantity":"1.0","unitPrice":"3.5"},{"itemId":"AQ1923","quantity":"3.0","unitPrice":"22.1"}],"amount":"73.8","orders":[]},{"customerId":"J01","customerName":"Jack and Co.","orderId":"89202-2093","orderItems":[{"itemId":"AQ1900","quantity":"8.0","unitPrice":"3.0"},{"itemId":"AQ1923","quantity":"10.0","unitPrice":"2.5"},{"itemId":"AQ1921","quantity":"2.0","unitPrice":"2.1"}],"amount":"53.2","orders":[]}]
```

Comment: Can you try this query? `select customerId,customerName,array(select as struct orderId,orderItems,amount from customers) as orders from customers`

Comment: @RiccoD This will work, but without the where condition will add all customers orders to each customer. Also, my issue with the update. If I do a joined select without `unnest` it works. 
`select customerId, customerName, array(select as struct orderId, orderItems,amount from customers where a.customerId = customerId)  from customers as a ;`

Comment: I see. Can you provide sample data and expected data? Just so the community members can easily help you out.

Comment: @RiccoD I have edited the question with sample data and schema. Hope it is clear now. Thanks for your help.